# Android Navigation Drawer App Icon in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have an app composed by different `Fragments`, some are equipped with a navigation drawer. 
I would like to add the navigation drawer app icon in the `MainActivity` `ActionBar` only if required by the active `Fragment` but I cannot figure out how to do it in a proper way.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Thanks @Slickelito but my problem is that I don't have any drawer in my 'MainActivity' (so I don't have anything to show/hide in the 'Fragments') and I don't know how and where to declare it. Do I have to create a fake drawer in the 'MainActivity' and to show/hide it in 'Fragments'? Sorry for my silly questions, I'm relatively new to Java/Android world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

whenever you select a fragment that don't want to display the navigation drawer icon.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in your code..

```
 mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

It will solve your problem... :)